# Sharing Different Image and Content on facebook through same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to share some content with Images on the facebook. The sharing conent should look like as the given reference image[image: Reference Image for sharing content]

I'm generating dynamic content with share button to share on facebook through the same page. I have searched a lot of things on internet but didnt found anything helpful yet.

I have tried the following code but this is deprecated from facebook show do not works fine

```
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
           link: "https://example.com/some_path",
            picture: "https://example.com/image/path",
            caption: "Some caption here",
            description: 'put some description here',

        });     
    });
```

Comment: You need to use Open Graph Meta tags.

Comment: Yeah I know i should add open graph meta tag.. but I can be only for 1 content.. I want it to be dynamic. as if I have 100 share button on the same page. and Each share button shares different content and Image

Answer (score 2):

This helped me.

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': urlpath ,
                'og:title': some_title,
                'og:description': some_description,
                'og:image': imagepath ,

            }
        })
    },
 function (response) {
//your code goes here
 });
```

Comment: Legend! Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': urlpath ,
                'og:title': some_title,
                'og:description': some_description,
                'og:image': imagepath ,

            }
        })
    },
 function (response) {
//your code goes here
 });
```

This aproach doesn`t work any more in 2019. [Check](http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript)  for updates

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using following link just add link like this.

```
`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=[URL]&title=[TITLE]&picture=[IMAGE]">FB Share</a>`
```

URL = Url which you want to share
   TITLE = Title which you ant to share
   IMAGE = Image whole path which you want to share dynamically.

This is works for me so i hope its helpful for you as well.

Comment: also set following meta tags IN <HEAD> TAG
<meta property="og:url" content="[CONTENT]" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="[TITLE]" />
<meta property="og:image" content="[URL]" />